# Regexp of certain length ignoring specified characters

Tags: regex

Assume we have some string of defined length, that could contain some delimiters, that are used only for user-friendly view.

Example: 9-digit string, "123456789", that could be presented like "123,456,789" or "123.456.789" or "1-234-5-67-89" or "123 456 789"

What I need, is a regexp, that could count length ignoring that delimiters. 
Something like `[\d|,\.\-\s]{9}`, but with only \d counting into {9} (any number of delimiter characters allowed... optionally, delimiter characters shouldn't exceed two in a row)

Comment: You aren’t using “delimiter” but meaning “separator”?  Or are you? **QUOTE**: *delimiter*: A “character” or “string” that sets bounds to an arbitrarily-sized textual object, not to be confused with a “separator” or “terminator”.  “To delimit” really just means “to surround” or “to enclose” (like these parentheses are doing).

Comment: Sure, "separator". Sorry for my English :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
^[-.,\s]*(?:\d[-.,\s]*){9}$
```

optionally, delimiter characters shouldn't exceed two in a row:

```
^[-.,\s]{0,2}(?:\d[-.,\s]{0,2}){9}$
```

Comment: Right, after posting the question I've come to something similar, partly like: (\d[ \-]{0,1}){11,13}  (in my case ^ and $ are not required, as the search goes through a piece of text)
Still, I wonder, what "(?: )" usage adds to this expression? Is it generally preferred to "( )" in case we need no backreferences?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of bothering my head about finding an appropriate regular expression that might do this, I would rather use more simple regular expressions to either:

- find all digits and check the number of matches, or
- remove all non-digits and check the length of the remaining.